# AddTransient with a dependancy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Please see the code below:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()

.AddTransient<OtherService, OtherService>()
.AddTransient<ProductService, ProductService>(sp =>
{
    Guid Id = Guid.Parse(configuration["Id"]);
        return new Product(Id, new OtherService());
}
```

This works as expected.  Is it possible to do something like this:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()

.AddTransient<OtherService, OtherService>()
.AddTransient<ProductService, ProductService>(sp =>
{
    var otherService = GetService<OtherService>();
    Guid Id = Guid.Parse(configuration["Id"]);
        return new Product(Id, otherService);
}
```

What is the proper way of doing this? It is a .NET Core console app.

Answer (score 2):

You are an overload of the [`AddTransient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddTransient__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___0__) method which gives you the `sp` parameter which is an instance of [`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netcore-2.2):

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()

.AddTransient<OtherService, OtherService>()
.AddTransient<ProductService, ProductService>(sp =>
{
    var otherService = sp.GetService<OtherService>();
                     //^^ <---this
    Guid Id = Guid.Parse(configuration["Id"]);
    return new Product(Id, otherService);
}
```